# Tortoise SVN does not update to HEAD revision correctly

Tags: tortoisesvn

When I commit to SVN and after that update both via the shell extension of Tortoise SVN, the update sets me back to the revision before my commit.

I can verify this in two ways.
First of all after my commit it says that after my commit I am at revision 22058 and after the update it tells my I am at revision 22057.
When I call "Check for Modifications" and choose "Check Repository" there, it tells me that the HEAD-Revision is 22058.
[image: HEAD revision is 22058]

Still an update yields "at revision 22057"

[image: Updates to revision 22057]

This even happens if I choose "Update to revision" and select "HEAD revision".

The only way to get the latest revision is deleting my entire working copy and checking it out again - but then the problem reoccurs when I commit again.

Answer (score 3):

Just for the record:

The problem was that TortoiseSVN was in offline mode.
The solution was to open the log view for the workspace root and then pressing F5.
Refreshing the log causes TortoiseSVN to switch back to online mode.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a sparse checkout? Alternatively, you've checked out a subdirectory where the last commit is in your working copy even though the repo has other, later commits that are not part of your WC.

A Quick run through "[Check for Modifications](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-wcstatus.html)" using the "check repository" button shows this is working as intended. The commit revs for the list of modified files is what's listed in those 2 values.

> At the bottom of the dialog you can see a summary of the range of
>   repository revisions in use in your working copy. These are the commit
>   revisions, not the update revisions; they represent the range of
>   revisions where these files were last committed, not the revisions to
>   which they have been updated. Note that the revision range shown
>   applies only to the items displayed, not to the entire working copy.
>   If you want to see that information for the whole working copy you
>   must check the Show unmodified files checkbox.

Comment: Since I'm not that familiar with SVN - how do I recognize a "sparse checkout"? The directory I've checked out is the "TRUNK" and it even happens when there are no other checkins on the whole repo (which I can verify by asking my colleagues who have access). - Or did I misunderstand your last sentence completely?

Comment: its difficult to diagnose from your question, so I offered pointers to where to look. A spare checkout is a partial one, where you choose subdirectories to checkout.

Comment: It seems that my TortoiseSVN was in some kind of "Offline Mode". After reading that up and pressing F5 inside the show log-view of the root folder of my workspace, everything works again.
I still wonder when and how I entered offline mode accidentally...