# Tortoise SVN not recognizing the correct revision as HEAD revision

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

The single most relevant thing I have found in searching is this [Tortoise SVN does not update to HEAD revision correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25542610/tortoise-svn-does-not-update-to-head-revision-correctly) However, the solution presented is inadequate, or wholly incorrect.

To explain, I did something that most would probably (arguably, rightly) look on as a bad thing. I file-shared a repository. It's just me and one other person working on this repository, so having a finnicky server setup and logins seemed excessive. It's not as though we're going to try to push competing commits at each other.

To explain in more detail, we have been using Tortoise SVN to operate a Subversion repository via Google Drive. One person makes a change to the project, commits, the repository is automatically updated to the cloud, then the cloud version is automatically updated to the other person's repository, where they can update their working version from it.

The problem is, the recipient's SVN does not recognize the new revisions at all, despite being literally the same repository as the person who committed the changes. We are on revision 7, and the repository they downloaded has revision 7 within it, but when they update their working copy they get revision 6. If they look in the logs they don't see revision 7 at all, only revision 6. Attempting to manually update to revision 7 instead of to the HEAD revision gets a 'no such revision' error message. Attempting to create a new working copy from the repository gets them a revision 6 copy.

Now, we did set up the more cumbersome svnserve solution, and that worked correctly for both parties, so I speculate that google drive is somehow the problem, but I am at a loss as to what the problem might *be*.

Please understand that I've never used a version control system before in my life, so it's very possible there is some crucial piece of information you need and I have no idea that you might need it.

I understand that the answer may simply be that this is a totally unworkable model, but I must know *why* before I can accept that answer.

Comment: Very poor choice of solution. Use git and host your project in a private gitlab repository.

Comment: you should never put Git or SVN repository on Google Drive or dropbox or any other similar service. Deploy your private server or use a hosted solution.